# Brief outage where all questions were gone

Tags: bug, questions

Just now, none of the sites I visited had any questions:

> [image]

I don't belong to Politics, but in addition to this I was getting a 404 by going to this [page](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions?page=2&sort=newest).

For sites that I belonged to, I was getting the error "it was not possible to perform this tag search at this time due to an unexpected error.":

[image]

[image]

(Both of the above are pictures from the home page.)

Comment: I am getting the same problem intermittently on Physics SE (one of the main SE's I visit multiple times a day). On the "questions" page I get zero questions reported. Refresh page (on Firefox 63.0.3 Linux 64-bit) does not fix the problem. Closing tab and reload a few moments later does seem to work.

Comment: Probably the tag-engine blipped ...